# Каким будет значение переменной result после выполнения следующего кода?

Tags: python

Почему ответ 5,25?
т.е почему `(x + True) = 21`, а `(4 - y * False) = 4`?

```
x = 20
y = 5
result = (x + True) / (4 - y * False)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
True = 1
False = 0
```

Поэтому

```
4 - y * False = 4 - y * 0 = 4 - 5 * 0 = 4
x + True = 20 + 1 = 21
```

Ну и `21 / 4 = 5.25`